# Firebase array became nil after loop in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to append element to array but it returns empty array. 
What I'm trying to do is put elements that match up with tags user selected.
To achieve that, first I created model.

```
//Model
    import UIKit
    import Firebase

        struct Team {

            var key: String
            var teamName: String
            var league: String
            var lat: Double
            var lng: Double

            init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                self.key = snapshot.key
                self.teamName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["teamName"] as? String
                self.league = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["league"] as? String ?? ""
                self.lat = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["lat"] as? Double ?? 0
                self.lng = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["lng"] as? Double ?? 0
            }
        }
```

firebase structure looks like this.

```
{
   "tags": {
       "NewYork": {
             uid1: 1
             uid2: 1
             uid3: 1
       }, 
      "baseball": {
             uid1: 1
       }
    }
}
```

First, I fetched uids that match up with the tags. Then retrieve team's info based on uids that matched up with. If the same uid comes in like uid1 above, I want Xcode to print something. To do that I implemented like so(is there a better way?) but it's never been executed because `results.count` is always 0 even if after appended. However right after append method(I commented //here) it returns team's info properly.

```
func filterTeam(filterTag: FilteredTags) {

            let tag = filterTag.selectedTag.components(separatedBy: "/") //this returns "NewYork" and "baseball"

            var results = [Team]()

            tag.forEach { (key) in

                ref.child("tags").child(key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else { return }
                    dictionary.forEach({ (uid,_) in

            if results.count == 0 {
                ref.child("teams").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshots) in
                    let team = Team(snapshot: snapshots)
                    results.append(team)
             //here         
                    print(results)
                }, withCancel: nil)
            } else {
                for result in results {
                    if result.key == uid {
                        print("same uid!!")
                    } else {
                        ref.child("teams").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshots) in
                            let team = Team(snapshot: snapshots)
                            results.append(team)
                        }, withCancel: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
     })
    }, withCancel: nil)
   }
 }//func
```

How can I append properly and achieve what I want to do. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** use `.count == 0` to check if a string or collection type is empty, there is a property: `if results.isEmpty`. And four times `snapshot.value as! NSDictionary` to get always the same object is unnecessary expensive. Besides don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I changed .isEmpty but result is the same. Can you tell why?

Comment: All `observe` calls work asynchronously. That's the normal behavior. You might use `DispatchGroup` to notify when the last iteration has finished.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but It doesn't work:(